# Ansible Task Creates option issue

Tags: ansible

I want to write an Ansible playbook to install a package only if a particular is not present, so when the `/tmp/hosted` file present installation should not proceed, but it's failing:

```
---
 - hosts: all
   sudo: yes
   tasks:
   - name: Ensure NTP (for time synchronization) is installed.
     yum:  name=ntp state=present
     args:
      creates: "/tmp/hosted"
```

Error:

```
[root@ns0 ansible]# ansible-playbook creates.yml -l ansi2
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Instead of sudo/sudo_user, use become/become_user and make sure become_method is 'sudo' (default).
This feature will be removed in
 a future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansi2]

TASK [Ensure NTP (for time synchronization) is installed.] ***********************************************************************************************
fatal: [ansi2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (yum) module: creates. Supported parameters include: conf_file,disable_gpg_check,disablerepo,enablerepo,exclude,install_repoquery,installroot,list,name,skip_broken,state,update_cache,validate_certs"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/creates.retry

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ansi2                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Check existence of /tmp/hosted
      shell: test -e /tmp/hosted
      register: hostedfile
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: Ensure NTP (for time synchronization) is installed.
      yum:  name=ntp state=present
      when: hostedfile.rc != 0
```

Comment: can I know wat would be the output of register ` hostedfile` if the file exists,,

Comment: Well it did  work , thanks alot and i guess i also learned wat the code  did , correct me if im wrong 

so the file `/tmp/hosted` existed so the register `hostedfile` value was `0` 
And the  `when `  directive in ntp installation  checked register  value it was `0` so it did not allowed ntp installation i.e   it would have allowed installation when the file was missing and it would have given 1 or some other value to  regisgter `hostedfile`

Comment: You are correct. But I have updated my answer to make the shell command more elegant; testing to see if the file exists rather than using `ls`. The `register: hostedfile` also contains the stderr and stdout of the shell command, in addition to the return code.